# Get ajax return value when calling aync method in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, ajax

On client side, I use this Jquery function to retrieve a value with ajax:

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "/my-page.aspx/checkout",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {

        alert(response.d);       

    },
    failure: function (response) {

        //alert(response.d);

    }

});
```

This is the server side async funtion:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
   public async static Task<string> checkout()

    {

        string r = await afrekenen();

        return r;
    }
```

I retrieve a value in the ajax success section, but it's of the type 'Object object'. Any idea how to solve this? Whit debugging, the return value of the method 'checkout()' is a string...

Comment: Try `console.log(response)` and tell us what is the output in console.

Comment: `alert()` only outputs strings. you're passing in an object, so you get the string representation of that object, which is the literal text `[Object object]`

Comment: @Sven But what did you expect to get? `complete` function gets Object as its first argument, so it obviously can't be a String - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. It is a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object.

Comment: It's can be a string @EugenePodskal, you could see that in Additional Notes in same documentation.

Comment: I return a string in c# so I hoped to get a string back in javascript ;-). When I use this way of working with a normal c# webmethod (no async method), I get a string as returnvalue... But this async method returns an object of type 'Task<string>', and I don't know how to get the string value of the returned object in javascript...

Comment: You aren't even posting any data and if you were you would need to stringify it yourself to send as json. Doesn't make sense to use `post` and not send anything

Comment: Why are you using `async`/`await` to begin with? AFAIK, this isn't supported in ASP.NET `WebMethod`s; it's an MVC/WebAPI thing.

Answer (score 0):

In this case  Async Return a type of  Task string 
and Task T include a 'Result' property to store a return value.
so, when you manipulate the  json object. It Should 
console.log(response.d.Result);
or do console.log(JSON.stringify(response.d)) and check includes other properties also.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.